# Google API is not returning the events created from UI

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I am using `googleapis` in NodeJS to create & fetch the calendar events. I am using the following method to get the list of events.

```
    const getEvents = async (dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd,timeZone) => {
    console.log("Date Start : " + dateTimeStart +  " date end :" + dateTimeEnd + " time zone " + timeZone);
    try {
        let response = await calendar.events.list({
            auth: auth,
            calendarId: CALENDER_ID,
            timeMin:  (new Date(dateTimeStart)).toISOString(),
            timeMax: (new Date(dateTimeEnd)).toISOString(),
            timeZone: timeZone,            
            singleEvents: true,
            maxResults: 9999,
            orderBy: 'startTime
           
        });

       
        let items = response['data']['items'];
        console.log(items);
        return items;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Error at getEvents --> ${error}`);
        return 0;
    }
};
```

The above method returns only events that are created programmatically via `googleapis`. If I create the events directly on the calendar from the browser this does not return those events.

Any idea how to fetch all events even if they are created from browser.

Comment: I just noticed when I create an event programmatically,  It shows me that the event is created by `calender@calender-343816.iam.gserviceaccount.com` and if I create the event directly from the browser it shows me event is created by `nabeel`. I think its something to do with user

Comment: Are you doing user impersonation when creating the events or just creating them directly with the service account?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you were explaining about the behavior of the events being created by the service account instead of the actual users I think the problem is that the events created through API are being created under the Calendar ID of the service account, and the ones created by the users through API may have a different Calendar ID, therefore when you try to get the list of events, since you are probably using the Calendar ID from the service account you get only those events created using the API and not the ones created by the users through the web UI.

In this case it may be necessary to make sure that every event is being created under the exact same calendar ID through the web UI and the API so that all the events no matter if they were created through the API or web UI get listed as expected.

Let me know if this is useful, otherwise I can edit the response to add more clarification depending on your specific situation.